# why we should use static keyword in dart in place of abstract?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, static, static-methods

I m preparing a class in my flutterfire project and their I want to use some method Which can't change further so that I want to know consept of static keyword in Dart ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"static" means a member is available on the class itself instead of on instances of the class. That's all it means, and it isn't used for anything else. static modifies *members*.

**Static methods**
Static methods (class methods) don’t operate on an instance, and thus don’t have access to this. They do, however, have access to static variables.

```
void main() {

 print(Car.numberOfWheels); //here we use a static variable.

//   print(Car.name);  // this gives an error we can not access this property without creating  an instance of Car class.

  print(Car.startCar());//here we use a static method.

  Car car = Car();
  car.name = 'Honda';
  print(car.name);
}

class Car{
static const numberOfWheels =4;
  Car({this.name});
  String name;
  
//   Static method
  static startCar(){
    return 'Car is starting';
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `static` keyword in Dart is used to declare a variable or method that belongs to just the class not the instances, which means the class has only one copy of that variable or method and those static variables (class variables) or static methods (class methods) cannot be used by the instances created by the class.

For example, if we declare a class:

```
class Foo {

    static String staticVariable = "Class variable";
    final String instanceVariable = "Instance variable";

    static void staticMethod(){
        print('This is static method');
    }

    void instanceMethod(){
        print('instance method');
    }
}
```

The thing here to remember is static variables are created only once and every instance created by the class has different instance variables. Therefore you can not call static variables form the class instances.
The following code is valid:

```
Foo.staticVariable; 
Foo().instanceVariable;
Foo.staticMethod();
Foo().instanceMethod();
```

But this will give errors:

```
Foo().staticVariable;
Foo.instanceVariable;
Foo().staticMethod;
Foo.instanceMethod
```

**Use of static variables and methods**

You can use static variables when you have constant values or common values that are relevant for the class.

You can read more [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods).